# php mode to html mode switch limit for php 7?

Tags: php, php-7

When switching from php to html ,is there a  php-mode to html-mode  php engine limit  / second  ?

```php
<div class="header">
 <?php echo 'here i am'; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

nope - no limit - earlier php was just a "template" language to add some variables to html code.. it was common just to write plain html code and then inject the php var where you need it... but you should consider using a template engine like twig to divide your
logic from template code